# How to prevent Canvas auto clear in android?

Tags: android, canvas, android-recyclerview, swipe, itemtouchhelper

I have a recyclerView that I added a itemTouchHelper callback that works with onTouch methods.

When I swipe and click anywhere outside of the viewholder it should make the button disappear and bring the viewholder back to its original location.

My problem is (only) when I swipe, touch the EditText and drag it down, the button I drew on the canvas seems to disappear. I tried to find where onChildDraw was called but it does not enter the function so I assume it has something to do with canvas itself.

[Example video to show the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aXQs.gif)

Comment: Consider posting your canvas code so we can best help you.

Comment: I used this tutorial: https://codeburst.io/android-swipe-menu-with-recyclerview-8f28a235ff28.